# Performance Of Joins in Spark-SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Assuming that we have a healthy cluster and for the use case we have

> two datasets with 1 Billlion + records

We need to compare both datasets and find out

> duplicates in the original dataset

I was planning to write a

> sql query with join on the columns that are to be checked for
>   duplicates

I wanted to know how will be the

> performance for this query and also the refinements

that can be done in the datasets(dataframe partitioning) before joining them.

Please do pitch in with your observations.

Comment: are both the datasets of 1 Billion records each?

Comment: Yes VRSA. Both are 1 billion plus

Comment: By "duplicates" do you mean tuples in data set 1 that are also present in data set 2?

Comment: Yes but the columns on which we want to check the duplicates are user configured . Suppose if I have 10 columns in both the datasets , user input will decide that how many columns do we have to check for same values .  It can be 1 to 10. Direct record level duplicate check is not the requirement

Comment: Ok, and do you require whole of the joined tuple to be returned in the results or just the columns users configured to match?

Comment: The required columns can be different from what user has specified for duplicate check

Answer (score 4):

> I wanted to know how will be the performance

Compared to what? As for absolute numbers, I think it will obviously depend on your data and your cluster.

However in Spark 2.0 performance improvements are quite significant.

> and the refinements

The Catalyst optimizer is pretty good (more so after 2.0). Underneath it takes care of most of your optimizations like column pruning, predicate push down etc. (In 2.0 there's also code generation that takes care of generating a very optimized code that achieves very large performance improvements.)

And these same improvements are available across the board whether you use DataFrames/Datasets API or SQL.

As an example of kind of query optimizations that Spark's catalyst does, lets say you have two dataframes df1 and df2 with same schema (as your case) and you want to join them on some columns to only get the intersection and output those tuples.

Let's say my schema for data frames is as following (calling `df.schema`):

```
StructType(
StructField(df.id,StringType,true), 
StructField(df.age,StringType,true), 
StructField(df.city,StringType,true), 
StructField(df.name,StringType,true))
```

that is we have id, age, city, name columns in my data sets.

Now given what you want to do you will do something like

```
df1.join(
    df2, 
    $"df2.name"===$"df1.name"
       ).select("df1.id","df1.name", "df1.age", "df1.city" ).show
```

If you look at the physical plan of the above you will notice many optimizations done under the hood by Catalyst optimizer:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*Project [df1.id#898, df1.name#904, df1.age#886, df1.city#892]
+- *BroadcastHashJoin [df1.name#904], [df2.name#880], Inner, BuildRight
   :- *Project [age#96 AS df1.age#886, city#97 AS df1.city#892, id#98 AS df1.id#898, name#99 AS df1.name#904]
   :  +- *Filter isnotnull(name#99)
   :     +- *Scan json [age#96,city#97,id#98,name#99] Format: JSON, PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(name)], ReadSchema: struct<age:string,city:string,id:string,name:string>
   +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, true]))
      +- *Project [name#99 AS df2.name#880]
         +- *Filter isnotnull(name#99)
            +- *Scan json [name#99] Format: JSON, PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(name)], ReadSchema: struct<name:string>
```

`

In particular notice that even though two same dataframes are being joined  they are being read differently --

1. Predicate push down: from the query it is evident to Spark that for df2 all you need is the `name` column (and not the entire record with `id, age` etc). Wouldn't it be great if this information is pushed down to location where my data is being read? That will save me from reading unnecessary data that I do not plan to use. That is exactly what Spark did ! For one side of the join Spark will only read `name` column. This line:
   `+- *Scan json [name#99] Format: JSON, PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(name)], ReadSchema: struct<name:string>` For the other side `df1` however, we want all four columns in the result after join. Again Spark figures this out and for that side it reads all four columns. This line: `+- *Scan json [age#96,city#97,id#98,name#99] Format: JSON, PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(name)], ReadSchema: struct<age:string,city:string,id:string,name:string>`
2. Also just after reading and before join Spark figured out that you're joining on `name` columns. So before join it removed the tuples that had name as `null`. This line: `+- *Filter isnotnull(name#99)`.

This means that Spark is already doing all this heavy lifting for you so that the minimum data is read and brought into memory (thus reducing shuffle and compute time).

However, for your specific case you might want to think whether you can reduce this data read further -- for at least one side of the join. What if you have many rows in df2 that have same combinations of keys against which you're matching the df1. Will you not be better off by first doing a distinct on df2? I.e. Something like:

```
df1.join(
    df2.select("df2.name").distinct, 
    $"df2.name"===$"df1.name"
   ).select("df1.id","df1.name", "df1.age", "df1.city" )
```

Answer (score 2):

The query performance for datasets of such order cannot be predicted but can be handled. I worked with a dataset of 700 million records and below are the highlight properties that helped tweaking my application.

- spark.sql.shuffle.partitions (finding the sweet spot on your own)
- spark.serializer (Preferably KryoSerializer)

Also allocating the cluster resources for your application matters a lot. Please refer to this [blog](https://0x0fff.com/spark-architecture-shuffle/). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks VRSA. Please can you also suggest me that how can I partition my dataset before joining as my join conditions are dynamic.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried increasing the executor core to 4 or more based on your cluster configuration and also while doing a spark-submit better  not to mention no. of executors. Let spark decide no. of executors to be used. This may improve the performance to some extent when working with huge datasets.

Comment: increasing executor cores will be coming at the execution level of optimization. right now I am trying to prepare my datasets and correct way to find the duplicates between them based on the columns.